# Combo box in Extjs editor grid not displaying initally

Tags: extjs

I am trying to edit an information using editor grid. I have three fields, Interview By (combo), Date (date) and Performance (number), I get the date and the performance column, but the combo is not displaying the value initially. But when I click, then it shows the correct value. I am new to extjs and googled it for a solution, but could not find it. Kindly help me with a solution. Thanks in advance.

**MY CODE:**

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.createTbar(); 
    this.columns = [
        { xtype:'numbercolumn', 
          hidden:true,
          dataIndex:'interview_id', 
          hideable:false
        },
        {   xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'interview_by_employee_id',
            header: 'Interview By',
            sortable: true,
            width: 290,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combo',
                store: employee_store,
                displayField:'employee_first_name',
                valueField: 'employee_id',
                hiddenName: 'employee_first_name',
                hiddenValue: 'employee_id',
                mode: 'remote',
                triggerAction: 'all',
                forceSelection: true,
                allowBlank: false ,
                editable: false,
                listClass : 'x-combo-list-small',
                style: 'font:normal 11px tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif'


        },
        renderer: function(val){
            index = employee_store.findExact('employee_id',val); 
            if (index != -1){
                rs = employee_store.getAt(index).data; 
                return rs.employee_first_name; 
            }
        }

        },
        {   xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'interview_date',
            header: 'Date',
            sortable: true,
            readOnly: true,
            width: 100,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'datefield'
            }
        },
        {   xtype: 'numbercolumn',
            header: 'Performance',
            format:'0',
            sortable: true,
            width: 100,
            align: 'right',
            dataIndex: 'interview_performance',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'numberfield'
            }
        }
    ];
    candidate_grid_interview.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
}
```

and the screen shots,

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and found my solution somewhere. Here is a reduced version of what I'm using. I think the key was the `renderer` property on the column. If your combo uses remote data, it might be loading its content after the grid is done loading - but I'm not sure it will cause the problem you're describing.

Try this concept:

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoLoad: false,
    ...            
    fields: [
        { name: 'myID', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'myName', type: 'string' }
    ],
    listeners: {
        load: function () {
            // Load my grid data.
        },
        scope: this
    }
});

var myCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    ...
    displayField: 'myName',            
    valueField: 'myID',
    store: myStore
});

var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
        ...
        fields: [                
            ...
            { name: 'myID', type: 'int' },
            ...                   
        ]
    }),
    ...
    cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
        columns: [
        ...
        {                
            header: 'Header',
            dataIndex: 'myID',                        
            editor: myCombo,                    
            renderer: function (value) {
                var record = myCombo.findRecord(myCombo.valueField, value);
                return record ? record.get(myCombo.displayField) : myCombo.valueNotFoundText;
            }
        }]
    })            
});

myStore.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Store loading is asynchronous, so it might be loading itself after rendering the grid. I recommend you render your grid within the store onload event. Also, datatypes can be painfull if you don't pay enough attention. Be sure that your grid store and combo store types match.